# Plancherel Theorem holds for Sobolev Space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that

> For $f,g\in S(\Bbb R^n)$ functions in Schwartz space. 
>   $$ \int f\bar{g} \,dx  = \int \hat{f} \bar{\hat{g}} \,dx   \quad  (*)$$

We define the Sobolev space $W^s$ to be the completion of $S(\Bbb R^n)$ under the sobolev $s$- norm.

Does $(*)$ still hold for this space?

---

I noticed an even more fundamental problem $(**)$:

I know that the Fourier inversion is well defined for $S(\Bbb R^n) \rightarrow S(\Bbb R^n)$, with $f \mapsto \hat{f}$. Does this induce a well defined map $W^s \rightarrow W^s$?

---

EDIT: I think the whole argument boils down to addressing the above question.

$$ ||\hat{f}_n||^2_s =  \int |f_n^{-}(x)|^2 (1+|x|^2)^s \, dx = ||f_n||_s^2$$ 
This implies the map is well defined.

The proof of $(*)$ also follows by applying Fourier transformation.